# How to create a reusable choice parameter for Jenkins builds

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a number of Jenkins builds which all require a similar choice list for entering one of the build parameters. For arguments sake this could be a drop down of countries.

If my countries drop down parameter is used in multiple Jenkins builds, and i need to add a new country, how can i avoid adding the new country in multiple places? i.e. how can i have a single list that i can update that will propagate to all builds rather than making the same update to a choice list in every build?

FYI I am using declarative syntax for my pipelines

Comment: Have you looked into [Extensible Choice Parameter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Extensible+Choice+Parameter+plugin)?

Comment: Have tried to look at extensible choice but documentation is very poor. Do you know of any tutorial on how to use it?

Comment: Don't think you need tutorial. In Jenkins system configuration, enable "Global Choice Parameter" and define your countries as choices. Then for parameter, select "Choice Provider" -> "Global Choice Parameter". See first 3 screenshots on linked page.

Answer (score 0):

This is somehow of a patch and a very dirty approach, but I think it could solve your problem: you could keep a select.json in `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace` and just reference that json within the Jenkinsfile in all your projects. To parse the json you could use *jq* in bash